# Throttle parallel flux with delayed elements

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In Project Reactor, how do you throttle a parallel flux with delayed elements, for example when dealing with api requests?

When executing this code ([jdoodle.com/ia/fjQ](http://jdoodle.com/ia/fjQ)):

```
Flux.range(0, 100) 
        .parallel() 
        .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .flatMap(i -> {
            System.out.println("make api call with huge payload");
            // return Mono.just(Mono.just(i).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis((long) (Math.random() * 500 + 500))).block());
            return Mono.just(i).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis((long) (Math.random() * 500 + 500)));
        })
        .doOnNext(i -> {
            //do something with the data
            System.out.println("Got data from request " + i);
        })
        .sequential() 
        //block for demonstration only so it's copy pasteable
        .blockLast();
```

all 100 API requets are fired at the same time. In my case the responses are huge and my consumers can't keep up with the incoming data, resulting in pretty high memory consumption. How do I achieve something like the commented line in the flatMap above, but without an inappropriate .block() call? With the .block() in place, the stream always waits for the data to be processed before making another api request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using concatMap instead of flatMap.